# OpenSSL Nuget package not installing in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, openssl-net

I am trying to install the OpenSSL Nuget package in VS 2015.

I get the error:

> Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'openssl.1.0.2.1' with respect to project 'BLL', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
>   Package 'openssl' is not found in the following primary source(s): 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'. Please verify all your online package sources are available.
>   ========== Finished ==========

I also tried running

> Install-Package openssl

from the Package Manager Console, but it did not work. It downloaded the "openssl.1.0.2.1.nupkg" file to my packages directory, but there are no other files.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSL package used for C++ project. And I get the same issue with you when installing the version 1.0.2.1. Then I download the OpenSSL package to local and open it with NuGet Package Explorer, I don't find any content files in this package.

I have submit this issue to OpenSSL package. Please add your comments to this feedback and please waiting response from the owner patiently.

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/1865

But when install the OpenSSL package 1.0.2, it doesn't get any error. So I suggest you install the version 1.0.2 in your project.